# Generate SecretKey from AndroidKeyStore

Tags: android, encryption, android-keystore, secret-key

According to this [sample](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.security.keystore.KeyProperties), I am trying to get `SecretKey` from `AndroidKeyStore`:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
keyStore.load(null);
SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
```

But I get this exception:

```
android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreRSAPrivateKey cannot be cast to javax.crypto.SecretKey
```

This is how I have created the key:

```
KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                    .setAlias(KEY_NAME)
                    .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + KEY_NAME))
                    .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(1337))
                    .setStartDate(START_TIME)
                    .setEndDate(END_TIME)
                    .build();
KeyPairGenerator kpGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");   
kpGenerator.initialize(spec);
kpGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

So is there any way to generate `SecretKey` from `AndroidKeyStore`?

Comment: `SecretKey` is used for symmetric keys not asymmetric keys.

Comment: @LukePark how can I generate symmetric key using `AndroidKeyStore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android 6.0 you can generate AES keys using AndroidKeystore:

```
KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "AndroidKeyStore");
kg.init(keySpec);
SecretKey key = kg.generateKey();
```

For more details see blog post [Keystore redesign in Android M](https://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2015/06/keystore-redesign-in-android-m.html)  (by Nikolay Elenkov).